# Custom link in an open graph story

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm building a facebook app which uses open graph to publish stories. I can successfully publish the stories but what I want to do is to customize the app link in the story(circled in the given image).

[image]

Currently my link to "posted via APP_NAME" is referring to the Facebook appcenter page of my app. All I want to do is to customize the link and make it refer to my personal website. How can I do that?

Do I have to specify any extra parameters while making a POST request to facebook??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this link leads to one of:

- Canvas URL if you have a canvas app
- Site URL if you have no canvas app just website with fb login

You can set both in App Settings (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)
Looking through the logs it's impossible to distinguish it from people just accessing the app.

Comment: I don't have a website with facebook login but an android app with facebook login. Can I still do it?

Comment: I think if you set one of those url (preferably site URL) to your page this should work!

Answer (score 1):

Add a canvas application with an address of page with this code:

```
<script>top.location.href = 'http://your-website.com'</script>
```